# Froala Editor: how can I prevent image alignment to center after inserting?

Tags: image, alignment, froala

It seems to be a default behavior that I like to disable: when you insert an image it is always centered and I have to align it to left afterwards. 
How can I disable this? I don't want the image to be centered automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Support helped me. It's this setting:

`imageDefaultAlign: 'left'`